# Rails: constant not initializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use different stripe keys (a credit card payment processing system) depending on whether I'm in test/development or production/ Based on suggestions I've seen on StackOverflow, I did the following:

In my /config/initalizers/stripe.rb file, I have the following:

```
STRIPE_CONFIG = begin
  config = YAML.load(File.open(Rails.root.join('config', 'stripe.yml')))
  config = config[Rails.env] || {}
  config.to_options
end
```

and in my /config/stripe.yml file, I have the following:

```
default: &default
  Stripe.api_key:    "testapikeycode"
  STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: "testpublickeycode"

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  Stripe.api_key:    "productionapikeycode"
  STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: "productionpublickeycode"
```

However, when I go into the console (rails console), and I type

```
puts STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
```

I get the following error message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
```

Any ideas?

## Alternate method

Only use stripe.rb, and have the following in it:

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  Stripe.api_key:    "productionapikeycode"
  STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: "productionpublickeycode"
else
  Stripe.api_key:    "tesapikeycode"
  STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: "testpublickeycode"     
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY is a key in your yaml config file, you never actually initialize it as a constant. If you type `p STRIPE_CONFIG['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']` instead you should get the result you want.

Aside I think `YAML.load` should be `YAML.load_file`.

Comment: YAML.load works. I ended up not using this, see my original question for comments